# Обученная нейронная сеть не может распознать мои рукописные числа, но прекрасно работает с тестовыми

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

не так давно проходил бесплатный курс по изучению ии, там мы обучали нейронную сеть распознавать рукописные числа.
В качестве базы данных, мы брали MNIST in CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets

from joblib import dump, load

mnist_train = pd.read_csv("mnist_train.csv", header=None)
mnist_test = pd.read_csv("mnist_test.csv", header=None)

train_data = mnist_train.values[:, 1:]
test_data = mnist_test.values[:, 1:]

train_label = mnist_train.values[:, 0]
test_label = mnist_test.values[:, 0]

kn_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1)

mlp_classifier = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(512,),verbose=True)
mlp_classifier = mlp_classifier.fit(train_data, train_label)
```

Идет обучение, в логе следующая информация

```
Iteration 1, loss = 1.77273886
Iteration 2, loss = 0.58012203
Iteration 3, loss = 0.35157180
...
Iteration 59, loss = 0.05635679
Iteration 60, loss = 0.05914925
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
```

Если тестировать на тестовых данных (mnist_test.csv), то ии способна распознать 96% картинок.

```
test_id = 724
plt.imshow(test_data[test_id, :].reshape(28, 28), cmap="Greys")
mlp_classifier.predict(test_data[test_id, :].reshape(1, 784))
```

Вот результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но теперь я хочу проверить на своих данных. Я нарисовал в Paint картинку 28х28px на которой изобразил число. Но нейронная сеть не может её распознать.

```
import numpy
import PIL

img = PIL.Image.open("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\two.png").convert("P")
imgarr = numpy.array(img)
plt.imshow(imgarr.reshape(28, 28), cmap="Greys")
mlp_classifier.predict(imgarr.reshape(1, 784))
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался изобразить максимально похожую шестерку, но даже так, она не распознал. А бывает, угадывает, но точность очень низкая.

**

> Дополнил вопрос

**

А если я делаю скрин, ранее распознанного числа, он прекрасно распознает мой вариант.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Делаю вывод

Если нарисовать цифру в более высоком разрешении (тестирую с 228х228), а после чего его сжать до 28х28 px и отдать на обработку, ии распознает цифру (но не всегда, % 70 что распознает) и то, 7 пожет перепутать с 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая размерность у `train_data`?

Comment: MaxU, 60000 рукописных чисел

Comment: что выводит `print(train_data.shape)` ?

Comment: вот это (60000, 784). с тестовыми данными, их там (10000, 784) отлично работает, аж 96% верных ответов.

Comment: Может из-за оттенок? Шестерка в mnist_test.csv имеет другие оттенки.

Comment: попробуйте использовать `.convert('LA')` вместо `.convert('P')`

Comment: Ругается на слишком длинный массив. `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1568 into shape (28,28)` Я сделал по другому, я сделал  скрин (первого скриншота, который в вопросе), выдал верный результат. Но почему мой почерк не может определить, не пойму.

Comment: Я немного отредактировал вопрос. Я добавил, что если делаю скриншот распознанного числа.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, вы обучили систему на сканах рукописных цифр а теперь пытаетесь заставить ее распознавать цифры, нарисованные в Paint?  Это как бы очень не одно и тоже. Попробуйте от руки написать цифры, отсканировать их а уже потом результат скормить системе. Что-то мне подсказывает, что точность должна повыситься.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, в описании сказано, что mnist  содержит двоичные изображения рукописных цифр. Но у меня сканера нет, могу только сфоткать, что и попробую сделать. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

При использованном методе обучения (по пикселам в конкретных координатах матрицы рисунка) очень важно, чтобы все части нарисованных цифр располагались всегда примерно на одних и тех же координатах. Малейший сдвиг влево/вправо или вверх/вниз, если таких примеров не было в обучении, приводит к тому, что такой алгоритм уже не способен правильно распознать цифры. Попробуйте рисовать ваши цифры примерно тех же очертаний и примерно на тех же ячейках, что и цифры в обучающей выборке.
Кроме того, нужно смотреть, какую "яркость" имеют пикселы в обучающей выборке и у вас. Если вы не делаете приведение пикселов картинок строго к значениям 255 и 0, то алгоритм может привязаться ещё и к "яркости" пикселов в обучающей выборке и примеры с другими значениями "яркости" опять же не будет способен опознать.
Именно из-за этих проблем в дальнейшем и были придумали разные методы обработки изображений вроде "конволюции" и прочих видов слоёв нейросетей, потому что они помогли распознавать изображения независимо от того, какая у них яркость пикселей и расположение "на холсте". Слои конволюции позволяют выделить границы изображений и некие шаблоны в этих изображениях, независимо от их яркости и расположения. Это позволяет гораздо лучше распознавать картинки (и не только).

**Дополнение**
Ещё есть вариант с "аугументацией" - это когда вы картинки из исходного датасета по-всякому немножко изменяете - крутите, сдвигаете, меняете яркость и т.д., и дополняете этими изменёнными картинками исходный датасет. И на всём этом потом учите нейросеть. В этом случае есть шанс, что нейросеть выучит более устойчивые какие-то признаки, по которым различаются цифры, а не случайные. Хотя в любом случае лучше всё-таки использовать для картинок `convolution` слои, они как-раз позволяют более надёжно выучить такие признаки без привязки к конкретным позициям признаков в картинках и т.п.